# Yalkut Yosef Mikveh

Tags: sources-mekorot, mikvah-ritual-bath

Can someone please post a photo of the page in Yalkut Yosef where he says one going to a cold mikveh he can think shemos hakedoshim and by a hot one a person can't.

Comment: do you know what page this is? https://hebrewbooks.org/2763

Comment: @rosends I strongly suspect that that's the wrong Sefer Yalkut Yosef. I think he means the one of Rav Ovadia Yosef's Pesakim.

Comment: Yes I'm referring to his sons sefer ^^

Comment: @Eliyahu with no clarification, there is no way to know which book by that name he intends, nor if he knows the page and is looking for a picture, or does not have the page and is hoping someone can find the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a picture but its a quote from Bar Ilan. I hope that helps. If not, let me know and I'll take a picture of it.

> ילקוט יוסף השכמת הבוקר סימן ד - מדיני בית המרחץ
>
> צו. הנכנס לחדר מקוה האר"י ז"ל בצפת, שלעולם המים שם צוננים, מותר לו לקרוא שם תהלים ולברך שם ברכות, אם אין שם באותה שעה בני אדם עירומים, וכן האומר עצמו מלובש בבגדים, שמאחר והמים שבמקוה לעולם הם צוננים, אין דין המקוה כדין בית מרחץ שאסרו לומר שם דברים שבקדושה. **וכן הדין בכל מעיין של מים צוננין**. [ואם יש שם בני אדם עירומים יהפוך פניו לצד אחר ויברך]. והיוצא ממקוה האר"י ולא טבל שם, אין צריך ליטול ידיו בצאתו. ואם טבל שם, מסתמא נגע בגופו במקומות המכוסים, וכשיצא משם יטול ידיו כדין הנוגע בגופו. **אבל בשאר המקוואות של מים חמים אסור לברך או לקרוא שם תהלים, אפילו אם אין שם בני אדם ערומים.)**

> הע צ"ו שם
>
> צו) אמירת תהלים במקוה האר"י ז"ל
>
> בגמרא שבת (י א) הנכנס לבית המרחץ, מקום שבני אדם עומדין לבושין, יש שם מקרא ותפלה, ואין צריך לומר שאילת שלום, ומניח תפילין ואין צריך לומר שאינו חולץ, מקום שבני אדם עומדים ערומים ולבושים, יש שם שאילת שלום, ולא מקרא ותפלה, ואינו חולץ תפילין, ואינו מניח לכתחלה. מקום שבני אדם עומדים ערומים, אין שם שאילת שלום, ואין צריך לומר מקרא ותפלה. וחולץ תפילין, ואין צריך לומר שאינו מניחן. ע"כ. וכן פסקו הפוסקים. **וכתב מרן הכסף משנה (פרק ג' מהלכות קריאת שמע הלכה ג') בשם רבינו מנוח, שיש לחלק בין מקוה צונן למקוה חם. דעיקר איסור המרחץ אינו אלא משום איסור זוהמא והבלא דאית ביה, על ידי שתשמישו בחמין. אבל הני מקוואות שהמים שלהם צוננים, ליכא זוהמא ומותר.** וגדולה מזו כתב בשו"ת חתם סופר (סימן רז) במי שיש לו בחדרו מקוה מים חמין לטהרת נשים, ומכוסה בנסרים, מאחר שהחדר הוא נקי וטהור, ורק פעם או פעמים חופפת אשה בתוכו, נהי דהחפירה נפישא זוהמא, מכל מקום החדר שהוא רשות לעצמה נקי והחפירה מכוסה, אין שום סברא לאסור ללמוד בו. אך מהיות טוב נכון לעשות מחיצה בינו לבין החפירה. וכן ראה למוהר"ז שהיה לו מקוה מכוסה בחדרו ולא שם. ע"כ. וכ"ש במקוה שהמים שבו תמיד צוננים, כמו מקוה האר"י. וראה באורך בשו"ת יביע אומר חלק ב' (חיו"ד סימן יד). ע"ש. וראה מה שהאריך בזה הרה"ג ר' בן ציון הכהן בשו"ת שערי ציון (סימן ג'). 
> ואמנם אין חדר המקוה חייב במזוזה, שהרי כתב מרן ביו"ד (סימן רפו סעיף ד') דבית הכסא ובית המרחץ ובית הטבילה פטורים לפי שאינם עשויים לדירת כבוד